# Trouble with file uploads in PHP

Tags: php, html, uploading, undefined-index

Here I have a basic html form with an choose file input and submit button. In my linked PHP page, I am trying to display the information of the file inside of an array in the browser, but am getting an undefined index error `Undefined index: file` on each of the two lines of code where my two variables are. Why am I getting this error?

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="mulitpart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <button type="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

My PHP code

```
  <?php

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    print_r($file);
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you spelt "multipart/form-data wrong"

Answer (score 1):

your enctype="mulitpart/form-data" must  enctype="multipart/form-data"

and then on your upload.php

```
$nameFile = $_FILES['file']['name']; //for name of picture
    $sizeFile = $_FILES['file']['size']; // for size picture
    $error = $_FILES['file']['error']; // for error 
    $tmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; //
```

if you want to show it you must convert to array like

```
$data [
$nameFile, $sizeFile, $error, $tmpName
];
```

and show with print_r($data);